# Entity framework Key attribute is not setting column as identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following:

```
public class FieldBookingMessageThread : MessageThread, ISoftDeletable, ITimeStamps, ICreatedBy
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FieldBookingMessageThreadID { get; set; }
}
```

There is nothing of interest in the MessageThread class.

When i run a data migration from Package Manager console, it does not seem to put `Identity:true` on that column.

I have created a custom data migration for that column:

```
AlterColumn( "dbo.FieldBookingMessageThreads", "FieldBookingMessageThreadID", c => c.Int( nullable: false, identity: true ) );
```

It runs fine with no errors but does not change the column to identity?

What might i be doing wrong?

**Quick solution which is obviously not the correct one:**

I have had to remove all my migrations. Create a fresh new migration. Delete my database, run the migration... And then everything seems to be okay. I've kept the old migrations just in case, sounds like a bug?

Comment: I remember the fix along the lines that you need to drop the table and re-create it, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute

```
public class FieldBookingMessageThread : MessageThread, ISoftDeletable, ITimeStamps, ICreatedBy
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FieldBookingMessageThreadID { get; set; }
}
```

Or

```
public class FieldBookingMessageThread : MessageThread, ISoftDeletable, ITimeStamps, ICreatedBy
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FieldBookingMessageThreadID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have applied this to all of my entity classes. I ran an `Add-Migration`, no updates are being made to the database?

Should i delete all my migrations and re run the new total database migration or something?

Comment: I had to delete all my migrations, delete my entire database.. and create a new migration. What on earth had gone wrong?